# How can I query a NCLOB column as a table in SAP HANA?

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I like to do a select query with a where condition on a column of type NCLOB let's call it `information` column. It has following format:

{
   "firstName" : "name1",
   "lastName" : "lastName1"
}

I want to do some thing like this

> Select * from myTable where information.firsName = "targetName"

But I am not sure how to do it.

Any hints please?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want a structured database instead of a JSON clob... :)

Why don't you have a look at the [JSON functions](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/f8f6916b5c434a6fbd1bb7e0dc65acd4.html) in HANA?

With `JSON_TABLE` you can construct a table structure "over" the JSON-data in the clob-column and then query that table structure.